# ActionbarSherlock home button not accessible below versions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbar sherlock and UriImageViewHelper library to set images to home icon.

Here is my code

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home);//(ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(view, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_PICTURE_URL)), R.drawable.no_img);
```

It works good on 3.0+ mobiles but crashing view = null on older versions.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because `android.R.id.home` was only introduced in 3.0. You have to find which one is the ID that `ActionBarSherlock` uses to replace it. Most likely it will be something similar to `com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.home`, but I'll let you explore that yourself.